# Edit Gridview Row ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edit

Struggling to edit a Gridview Row. Once I hit edit the gridview disappears, I guess because I only bind the grid on !IsPostBack - although the tutorial tells me to do it this way.

I have tried rebinding on postback which lets me edit the gridview but keeps the default values - not the new values.

Any help appreciated.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["Order_ID"] != null)
    {
        showgrid(int.Parse(Session["Order_ID"].ToString()));
    }
}

public void showgrid(int Order_ID)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString());

    string sqlstring = "Removed - is working";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gv_ExistingAds.DataSource = ds;
        gv_ExistingAds.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv_ExistingAds.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    showgrid(int.Parse(Session["Order_ID"].ToString()));
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label lb = (Label)gv_ExistingAds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label3");

    TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)gv_ExistingAds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3");

    string tx11 = tx1.Text;

    gv_ExistingAds.EditIndex = -1;
    showgrid(int.Parse(Session["Order_ID"].ToString()));
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" EmptyDataText="This order has no ads..."
    ID="gv_ExistingAds" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    Visible="true" DataKeyNames="Orders_Editions_ID, Cancelled, Order_ID" EnableViewState="true" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Publication Title" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="Publication_Title" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Insertion Date" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="Insertion_Date" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Advert Type" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ad_Size" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Revenue" HeaderText="Revenue" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note" ItemStyle-Width="150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemStyle Width="165px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_UpdateAdvert" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandName="Update_Advert" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Orders_Editions_ID")%>' runat="server" Text="Update" CausesValidation="false" />--%>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_CancelAdvert" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-xs" CommandName="Cancel_Advert" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Orders_Editions_ID")%>' runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_DeleteAdvert" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs" CommandName="Delete_Advert" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Orders_Editions_ID")%>' runat="server" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF6699" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Stripped your snippet down a bit, but it's working here. Are you sure `Session["Order_ID"]` is not emptied or overwritten after the first `DataBind()` in the IsPostback?

Comment: No - checking in immediate window shows me the order ID in session state. I also tried storing the datasource in a viewstate. It still vanishes though and shows my empty data text on postback. I have the gridview wrapped in an update panel and have tried taking it out of it, still the same.

Comment: Update to add that if I move it out of !IsPostBack completely I get the edit template to show but on update it keeps the previously binded data not the new data.

Comment: I had another method which was breaking it - also moved the initial bind outside of the !isPostBack and is now working.